# Powerapps create and edit in one screen

Tags: powerapps

We have a need to have just one screen for creating and then editing the record in the same screen. So I don't know if we can create a record and then edit it in the same screen. We are using CRM as our data source.

Comment: What you can do is to use a "New Form" and "Edit Form" with the "Visible" property as "false" then in your OnCreate or OnVisible property of the screen you can show the edit or new form depends of what are you going to do.

Answer (score 1):

PowerApps does support create and edit from the same screen using the Edit Form.  You can see this working by creating an "App from Data".  This creates a three screen app with a BrowserScreen, DetailScreen (read-only form), and EditScreen (editable form).  The later is used for both creating and editing records.

The steps to create this example is:

- New > Start with your data > Dynamics 365 > Phone layout
- Select the connection to the Dynamics 365 instance
- Select the entity to use as the datasource
- Click on the "+" icon on the BrowseScreen to see the following OnSelect expression:

  `NewForm(EditForm1);Navigate(EditScreen1, ScreenTransition.None)`
- Click on the pencil icon on the DetailScreen to see the following OnSelect expression:

  `EditForm(EditForm1);Navigate(EditScreen1, ScreenTransition.None)`